# FIrebase OTP issue for particular numbers/country

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I have implemented Firebase OTP in Flutter application but stuck with the errors:

```
E/FirebaseAuth( 7053): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17006 null

I/flutter ( 7053): [firebase_auth/operation-not-allowed] The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.
```

Its working fine for most of the phone numbers. I'm getting this issue for mainly 'Kuwait' based phone numbers.

- I've enabled 'Phone number' as sign in option
- Updated SHA1 ans SHA256 certificate fingerprints.
- Tried clearing user account list in case of if any numbers are blocked.
  My code:

  ```
    Future<void> sendOTP(String number) async {    
     await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
     phoneNumber: countryCode+number,      
     timeout: const Duration(seconds: 20),
     verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
       print("Auth Completed!");
     },
     verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
       print("Auth Failed!");        
       print(e);
     },
     codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
       print("OTP Sent!");
       verID = verificationId;
       return;        
       print(verID);
     },
     codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
       print("Timeout!");
     },
   );
  ```

  }

How do I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: did you make sure to use   .getRegionInfoFromPhoneNumber() passing number and isocode to always have a valid phone number?

Comment: @MarcelDz Actually im having trouble in test numbers also. Ive correctly given the numbers but those with Kuwait country code fails.

Comment: can you share example kuwait number ?

Comment: @AkshayGupta +965 699XXXXX

Answer (score 0):

Checklist:

1. Don't use the same number again and again, If you want to do so, add it to testing number in firebase console.
2. Disable all others auth methods like google/email sign in.
3. Download your .json/.plist file again after adding sha1/sha256.

Answer (score 0):

The error says clearly:
-Enable the phone auth under the authentication section of firebase